# Android - Layout for both Galaxy S4 and Nexus 5

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a specific qualifier I can use in order to make different
Layouts specifically for Nexus 5?

I'm using **layout-xhdpi** for devices such as Galaxy S4 (I've checked on S4 Active which has physical keys) and Note 2, and I don't want to change anything there.

**EDIT #2**
The cause of difference between S4 and Nexus 5, not considering the fact that the Layout is not optimal, is that the effective screen size is not as Galaxy S4 (1920) but smaller - 1776, because of the soft keys.

**EDIT #3**
This is the new layout with only one Relative Layout: (the problem is that **android:id="@+id/nextlevel"** is located behind **android:id="@+id/banner_adview"**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bg"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/endlevel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/congratulations"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/endlevel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/congratulations"
    android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/summary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/congratulations"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/levelendresultbg" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pointstext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/congratulations"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/pointstext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/divider" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/totalpointstext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/divider"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#e1c736"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/award"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/endlevel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/congratulations"
    android:src="@drawable/award" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topborder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/totalpointstext"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/topborder"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottomborder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/nextlevel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/bottomborder"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/nextlevelbutton"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/banner_adview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:background="@drawable/adback" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should really consider reviewing how you are building your layouts if you are considering device specific layouts. Focus instead on building scalable layouts that expand as you want using layouts such as `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`

Comment: It's the only device I'm having trouble with. Most Layouts are Relative and all of them using dp/sp measurments.

Comment: one thing in my mind right now, if(isNexus5) setContentView(R.layout.name_nexus_5) else setContentView(R.layout.name)

Comment: Then why don't you post your layout and some screenshots of the problem you are having? Somehow others are able to use the same layouts for all those devices.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have added the info to the original question. Tx!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because I've edited it so many times, that is became irrlevant, not constructive and not connected to the original question

Answer (score 4):

If you have a layout with layout-xhdpi or layout-xhdpi, you're probably doing something wrong in the first place.

The -xhdpi and -xxhdpi qualifiers will affect mostly the drawables, not the layouts (that is unless, you have a background image that takes the entire width or height of a layout).

For layouts, you generally have to use the size qualifiers, not the density qualifiers. And for the densities, what you must modify are the drawables, not the layouts.

Comment: I have added extra info to the original question, Thanks! :)

Comment: I didn't plan to use different layouts, but the question is how come the same layout works fine on Galaxy S4 (1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.0 inches (~441 ppi pixel density) but doesn't on Nexus 5 (1080 x 1920 pixels, 4.95 inches (~445 ppi pixel density).

Comment: The layout code you posted shouldn't work on *any* phone. You must have made some cutting and pasting mistakes. That being said, that's not the biggest issue. With this kind of layout, you should be using just one RelativeLayout, and using properties like layout_below or layout_alignblahblah... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: Start from the example I provided in the previous link and try to build your layout from scratch one element at a time. Do not use the Eclipse/Android Studio layout designer tools. Try to understand what you're doing. Only use the IDE to point out your syntax errors. Don't blindly copy an example you don't understand. The RelativeLayout properties actually make sense if you try to understand them. You may not know the exact syntaxes, but that's ok,  if you focus on making one little change at a time and if you help yourself with the guide I linked to, you can slowly make your way through it.

Comment: Thanks, though I think the screenshot I provided might be misleading, because of the parts I had to hide. I know pretty well most, if not all, Relative Layout properties.
I will go over it again, but I still doesn't understand why the same layout works fine on Galaxy S4 (1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.0 inches (~441 ppi pixel density) but doesn't on Nexus 5 (1080 x 1920 pixels, 4.95 inches (~445 ppi pixel density).

Comment: Don't tell me you "know" the RelativeLayout properties, **show** me you understand those properties by posting an attempted correction (throw everything away and start over from scratch). Post a corrected xml layout with only one RelativeLayout. As it stands, your current layout tells me you initially used only one Relative Layout, but since  all your views were overlayed on top of each other on the top left of the screen, you basically freaked out and took some quick corrective action without really understanding what was happening underlying everything.

Comment: And the main reason it worked on a Galaxy S4 is because that's the first device profile you used to test your layout against. If you tinker long enough with something, you're bound to find something that works with it eventually. Furthermore, your code as it stands can't even compile. So in my opinion, you made so many modifications to this code (not just copy and paste errors), that you don't remember all the modifications you made, nor do you remember which snapshot of the code ran "correctly" either (I'm placing correctly in quote marks).

Comment: I don't have a problem creating the same layout with only one Relative layout (I'll post in a few minutes). Though I try to understand how would this might make a change considering the fact that both devices are the same size and density, but one of them uses some of the screen for soft keys, which take up exactly the space I'm missing.

Comment: Like I said already, the layout code you posted on here can not possibly be the same layout code you have on your Galaxy S4 anyway. Can we even assume you used the same apk between the two device profiles? I personally can't. Feel free to wonder all you like, but I'm not going to speculate on what happened without seeing the actual code that's on there. Also, don't confuse the logical size of a screen with its actual hardware size. Barring a few exceptions, the android soft keys in the screen reduce the total size that's made available to applications to use.

Comment: OK, I don't think this question is going to be constructive, thank you for your effort.